# Principles of composition: how to lay out images in text?

Tags: images, page-layout, composition

What are some guiding design principles for laying out images in several paragraphs of text on a webpage?

In my particular case, there are two columns of text, and the images are proportioned and oriented like upright golden rectangles. They're roughly a third of a column in width. And they're just illustrative, as in a magazine; they're not figures that are referenced by the text:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is a little difficult to answer but is really interesting. The problem is right now we'd have to postulate many, many different layouts to come up with something. Could you go into a little more specific like how many images you need to include and what type of outlines they have? The goal is the editorial / ad / page can also play a role in this.

Comment: @Ryan, no particular outline, just the edge of the image. It's an informational webpage about a research lab.

Comment: post some screenshots, even if you change the content to filler if you can't publish the real stuff. It'll be a lot easier to help you figure this out and offer advice that way.

Comment: @Ryan, uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: There's not a whole lot of control in this regard on the web. Some suggestions, though, would be, in general: don't set type in columns online (one column is usually preferred); don't force-justify text; provide sufficient margins around images.

Comment: DA01, Ok, thanks, that's helpful. What do you mean by force-justify? Is that any different than justify?

Comment: @Will there is Aligned Left, Aligned Center, Aligned Right--- then there's Justified, Justified Left, Justified Center, and Justified Right. When justified which is commonly done in columns the sentences are all spaced in a way so that a letter is flush with the left and right side of the column. The Justified Side such as Justified Left would refer to the last line being flush only on one side, which is the case in the screenshot you posted. It causes large gaps in text and rivers (vertical gaps) to occur such as, "...the brain are capable of generating it, a theoretical..."

Comment: @Ryan, I see, thanks. I'm simply using the CSS property `text-align: justify`; it [doesn't seem that there's any properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) for the more nuanced flavors. Do you know a way of getting prettier justification with CSS?